# Why controller.should_receive(:before_filter_name) fails in rspec?

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

We uses `controller.should_receive(:before_filter_name)` in Rspec to by pass the before filter in our rails 3.2 rspec. But for some `before filter`, Rspec returns error.

Here is the def of before filter `check_availability`:

```
def check_availability
      if find_config_const('sales_lead', 'customerx').nil? or find_config_const('sales_lead', 'customerx') == 'false'
        redirect_to authentify.signin_path, :notice => "Quit!"
      end
end
```

In controller, the before filter:

```
before_filter :require_employee
before_filter :load_customer
before_filter :check_availability
```

To by-pass the `check_availability`, we put the following code in Rspec for the controller:

```
before(:each) do
      controller.should_receive(:require_signin) 
      controller.should_receive(:check_availability)          
end
```

Filter `require_signin` has no problem. However for the second filter, there is an error:

```
 2) Customerx::SalesLeadsController GET 'new' should redirect user without proper right
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mcontroller.should_receive(:check_availability)←[0m
       ←[31m(#<Customerx::SalesLeadsController:0x6fb3478>).check_availability(any args)←[0m
       ←[31m    expected: 1 time←[0m
       ←[31m    received: 0 times←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/controllers/customerx/sales_leads_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Customerx>'←[0m
```

We don't quite understand how `should_receive` works here. We have seen a few cases like this and would like to find out what causes the Rspec to fail.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to diagnosis this, at least from my perspective. If you share more of your spec and your controller, you might get more help. You may not be interacting with the same instance of the controller that you are mocking, for example.

Comment: Added a few lines of code in controller. it is indeed very simple code...

Comment: That's still not enough information. You haven't shown how `controller` is defined in your example and you haven't shown the example code (i.e. the body of the `it`).